# minimum value of a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Q:
What is the minimum value of $$\cos(2x)+3\sin(2x)$$ ?
(a question from my book)
I know minimum value of $\cos$ and $\sin$ is $-1$. So I thought that minimum value of this equation is $-1 + 3*-1 = -4$ , but $-4$ is not present in options. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Do you know about derivatives yet?   Otherwise you may consider a trig identity.

Comment: Diving and multiply by $\sqrt{10}$ and find some new sines and cosines. You'd find an interesting thing ;)

Comment: i don't. do i need to use double angle identity ?

Comment: Hint You'd be having something like $\sqrt{10} (\cos\phi \cos 2x+ \sin \phi \sin 2x)$

Comment: The two terms indeed respectively have a min of $-1$ and $-3$, but these are not attained simultaneously. If $\sin(2x)$ is close to $-1$ then $\cos(2x)$ is close to $0$. You can solve the problem by using the addition law for $\sin(a+b)$.

Comment: Phase shift identity: $a\cos \theta + b \sin \theta = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin(\theta + \phi),$ where $\tan \phi = b/a.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that if you took both of your coefficients, $1$ (in front of cosine) and $3$ (in front of sine), and were to create a triangle with side lengths $1$ and $3$, the hypotenuse would have a length of $\sqrt{10}$ (pythagorean theorem). This is why in the comments that number was popping up. So, multiply your equation by $\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{10}}$, which is of course $1$, so you are not altering your expression in any way.

Now, you have:

$$\sqrt{10}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\cos(2x)+\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\sin(2x))$$

From here, recognize that the angle $\phi$ of this triangle you made would have the identities $\cos(\phi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$ and $\sin(\phi) = \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$. Substituting this in, we have:

$$\sqrt{10}(\cos(\phi)\cos(2x)+\sin(\phi)\sin(2x))$$

And, remembering the sum formula for cosine, this is:

$$\sqrt{10}\cos(2x-\phi)$$

Which has a maximum of $\sqrt{10}$ and a minimum of $-\sqrt{10}$, since the cosine function has max/min of $\pm 1$.